# Extract value of version defined in package.json in bamboo task

Tags: bamboo, package.json

Is it possible to extract a *package.json* version value in a bamboo task? I want to extract the version field and save its value in a *bamboo.variable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try adding "Script" task into your Bamboo Job. In the script body you can add a code to read package.json version by using *grep* function from *cat* command output, and assign to a variable you like, e.g. PACKAGE_VERSION:

```
# Version key/value should be on his own line
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json \
  | grep version \
  | head -1 \
  | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' \
  | sed 's/[",]//g')

echo $PACKAGE_VERSION
```

[Code snippet source](https://gist.github.com/DarrenN/8c6a5b969481725a4413)

Comment: for linux machines, this solution is ok, I think

Answer (score 0):

Your better off using a custom script task (similar to what is described above). There is no component in Bamboo that provides this level of functionality out of the box.